# how to parse this nested json response?

Tags: java, android, json

I am getting  json response in this format.

```
{
   "apiGroups":
   {
       "Affiliate":
       {
           "listingsAvailable":
           {
               "Beauty_Personal_Care":
               {
                   "listingVersions":
                   {
                       "v1":
                       {
                           "get": "http://affiliate-feeds.snapdeal.com/feed/api/category/v1:586:821655440?expiresAt=1446085800024&signature=civtucyhsbufsjzjvqfa"
                       }
                   }
               },
               "Eyewear":
               {
                   "listingVersions":
                   {
                       "v1":
                       {
                           "get": "http://affiliate-feeds.snapdeal.com/feed/api/category/v1:473:662748456716?expiresAt=1446085800024&signature=civtucyhsbufsjzjvqfa"
                       }
                   }
               },
               "Real_Estate":
               {
                   "listingVersions":
                   {
                       "v1":
                       {
                           "get": "http://affiliate-feeds.snapdeal.com/feed/api/category/v1:897:673143570606?expiresAt=1446085800024&signature=civtucyhsbufsjzjvqfa"
                       }
                   }
               },
               "Jewellery":
               {
                   "listingVersions":
                   {
                       "v1":
                       {
                           "get": "http://affiliate-feeds.snapdeal.com/feed/api/category/v1:6:315773046?expiresAt=1446085800024&signature=civtucyhsbufsjzjvqfa"
                       }
                   }
               },
               "Furniture":
               {
                   "listingVersions":
                   {
                       "v1":
                       {
                           "get": "http://affiliate-feeds.snapdeal.com/feed/api/category/v1:580:1894930153?expiresAt=1446085800024&signature=civtucyhsbufsjzjvqfa"
                       }
                   }
               },
               "Tweens_Boys":
               {
                   "listingVersions":
                   {
                       "v1":
                       {
                           "get": "http://affiliate-feeds.snapdeal.com/feed/api/category/v1:814:934253466?expiresAt=1446085800024&signature=civtucyhsbufsjzjvqfa"
                       }
                   }
               },
               "Automobiles":
               {
                   "listingVersions":
                   {
                       "v1":
                       {
                           "get": "http://affiliate-feeds.snapdeal.com/feed/api/category/v1:1145:639299259208?expiresAt=1446085800024&signature=civtucyhsbufsjzjvqfa"
                       }
                   }
               },
               "Home_Improvement":
               {
                   "listingVersions":
                   {
                       "v1":
                       {
                           "get": "http://affiliate-feeds.snapdeal.com/feed/api/category/v1:864:624389489778?expiresAt=1446085800024&signature=civtucyhsbufsjzjvqfa"
                       }
                   }
               },
               "The_Designer_Studio":
               {
                   "listingVersions":
                   {
                       "v1":
                       {
                           "get": "http://affiliate-feeds.snapdeal.com/feed/api/category/v1:924:655684426383?expiresAt=1446085800024&signature=civtucyhsbufsjzjvqfa"
                       }
                   }
               },
               "Fashion_Jewellery":
               {
                   "listingVersions":
                   {
                       "v1":
                       {
                           "get": "http://affiliate-feeds.snapdeal.com/feed/api/category/v1:1113:672114192240?expiresAt=1446085800024&signature=civtucyhsbufsjzjvqfa"
                       }
                   }
               },
```

I need to get categories like beauty personal care, eye ware and their respective urls in get field.How can i loop through this and get the.So far i tried like this and dont no how to proceed next.Can anybody give me suggestions how to parse this json?

```
json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(response);
JSONObject api = json.getJSONObject("apiGroups");
JSONObject affiliate = api.getJSONObject("Affiliate");
JSONObject list = affiliate.getJSONObject("listingsAvailable");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: Your json is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) about the `JSONObject` class in Android.
In this documentation, you will find the method [keys](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys%28%29) that will "Returns an iterator of the String names in this object."

So you just have to call this method and use the iterator.

```
Iterator<String> keysIterator = jsonObject.keys();
String key;
while (keysIterator.hasNext()) {
     key = keysIterator.next();
     //use the key to retrieve the data form jsonObject
}
```

However, if you are the one generating this json, you may consider changing it a bit. The data in the *listingsAvailable* should probably be in an array.